# How to import API data via Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, api-design

I am trying to import some weather data via an API key, at the moment I am only trying to display the data before formatting.

Basically I need to create a weather data viewer by selecting one specific city via 2 drop down menus, one to select the country, one to select the city and after display the data. At the moment I can only select the country (before creating my jquery var, the second drop down menu was working correctly)

Here the Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Uk Weather Data</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ajaxjqueryload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Weather Uk Data</h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        <select id="countries">
            <option selected>Select a Country</option>
            <option value="england-cities">England</option>
            <option value="scotland-cities">Scotland</option>
            <option value="wales-cities">Wales</option>
            <option value="nireland-cities">Northern Ireland</option>
        </select>
        <select id="cities">
            <option selected>
                << Please Select a city</option>
        </select>
        <div id="cityData"></div>
        <div id="info"></div>
    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

And here my jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#countries').change(function() {
             $('#cities').load($(this).val() + '.html');
             $('#cities').change(function) {
                 var weatherData = $(this).val();
                 var weather = $('#cityData option:selected').text();
                 var apiUrl = 'http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=45e394a5e9c6d16ba8755822834a7127&info=' + weatherData;
                 $.ajax({
                         url: 'apiUrl',
                         type: 'GET'
                         dataType: 'json'
                         success: function(response) {
                             console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                         }
                     },
                     error: function() {

                     }
                 })
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: That javascript is badly formated and spelled.

Comment: I am following the script from my lecturer at university, in which way is it bad?

Comment: I placed you code in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjrgb3sb/), it gives an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` (check in on the broser console). Something is wrong with the `(` and the `{`. Did you type that or did you copy it from some file? Something is messed up.

Comment: I am using my my course as support but I did it alone, I a bit suspicious about that bit :    $('#cities').load($(this).val() + '.html');
                            $('#cities').change(function) {
                             var weatherData = $(this).val();    But I am not sure at all how to fix the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0e9784e4/ Here you go..

Comment: @Boratzan thanks, this version seems to help me with my drop down menu, but my api doesn't not work, I do not have the data visible on my web page.

Comment: @Jullian-lucBarber Probably because you don't supplied a valid access key. See http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=45e394a5e9c6d16ba8755822834a7127&info=test

Comment: @Boratzan the key is from today and should work, I don't really understand what is the problem, I don't know how to double check if a key is valid or not ?

Comment: @Jullian-lucBarber Check the response of your ajax call within a debugger. What does your console.log return?

Comment: @Boratzan nothing that is the problem, I do not have any return.

Comment: Well then, the only way I could help is by providing a URL. I can't guess what your doing wrong, it could be a lot of things.

Comment: Well after some research and work I now how this error on my console:    Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID=b3a1838aa853384aaf2616fda98768242655603. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).